# Build internal dashboard analytics on top of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, analytics, startup, dashboard, worker

I want to build an internal dashboard to show the key metrics of a startup.
All data is stored in a mongodb database on Mongolab (SaaS on top of AWS).
Queries to aggregate datas from all documents take 1-10minutes.

What is the best practice to cache such data and make it immediately available?

Should I run a worker thread once a day and store the result somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to build an internal dashboard to show the key metrics of a startup. All data is stored in a mongodb database on Mongolab (SaaS on top of AWS). Queries to aggregate datas from all documents take 1-10minutes.

Generally users aren't happy to wait on the order of minutes to interact with dashboard metrics, so it is common to pre-aggregate using suitable formats to support more realtime interaction.

For example, with time series data you might want to present summaries with different granularity for charts (minute, hour, day, week, ...). The MongoDB manual includes some examples of [Pre-Aggregated Reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) using time-based metrics from web server access logs.

> What is the best practice to cache such data and make it immediately available?
>
> Should I run a worker thread once a day and store the result somewhere?

How and when to pre-aggregate will depend on the source and interdependency of your metrics as well as your use case requirements. Since use cases vary wildly, the only general best practice that comes to mind is that a startup probably doesn't want to be investing too much developer time in building their own dashboard tool (unless that's a core part of the product offering).

There are plenty of dashboard frameworks and reporting/BI tools available in both open source and commercial flavours.